# Advice on trying to determine the rankings of my keywords via PHP

Tags: google, search

I've written a piece of code, which crawls the search engines, first 40 50 results
and check's for the specified keywords and tries to gather some statistics for them.

I've heard that this may be called content scraping but i really don't think that
this is the issue here since i would only call it maybe twice a day, on a set of
keywords that i think will be relevant to my service.

For using SEOmoz and other players in the game, i really think it's unfair because
it's really much they want for some simple keyword tracking.

Please give me some advice on what can go wrong and what would be a good way.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only running the script a few times a day then it's unlikely anything will actually go wrong. The main issue are as follows:

- You need to supply a dummy useragent similar to one produced by a browser
- Search results vary depending on factors such as the IP you're using so you might not get results that are as useful as they seem
- Google regularly changes the way they display results and it could break your code so it needs to be updated

Google terms what you are doing "Screen Scraping" and this is against their usage terms of service no matter how few times the script is run. They state that this is because it puts excessive loads on their servers.

However, I think that there's probably a copyright issue as well. If they let people easily copy their content then it would be possible to create a very cheap search engine that takes results from Google but replaces the ads. Google spends a lot of money on their search algorithm and needs to collect ad revenues to make a profit and continue development.

I guess that they also don't want marketers running these types of script because they don't want SEO's trying to gain insights they can use the unfairly manipulate rankings. There might be a similar issue for AdWords where they don't want marketers knowing too much about the keywords and ads that their competitors are using.

The main defense that Google uses against automated scripts is to temporarily block IP's that issue too many requests within a short period of time. As I stated earlier, your script shouldn't run into this problem but people issuing large numbers of queries usually use proxy servers to make regular IP changes and reduce the chance of detection.

Finally, this is beyond the scope of the question but another issue this type of script faces is that they also violate the terms of service of other Google systems. For example, the AdWords API TOS explicitly states you can't use the API with such a program. This could lead to API Developer Tokens being revoked on detection of these methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google's web search API](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=google%20search%20api&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=38664e7e8c090ddc&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=38664e7e8c090ddc&ion=1) and you won't be content scraping anymore. (I linked to the search results since it returned a lot of resources on the topic).

Comment: Hello john, thank you for your answer. However, there is no "search api" that google provides so that you can search the web for it.
You may only search *some* pages, e.g. a list of pages with this, so called, api.
Here is a list of the useless apis http://code.google.com/more/#google-search

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use their custom search API? It looks like it will do exactly what you need.

Comment: Because, quote:
"Google Custom Search enables you to search over a website or a collection of websites."
I would need this for the google results, to track my keywords. This is sad.

Comment: So make a collection of websites for the terms you are researching and then use the api to do your querying and reporting

Comment: Yes but, i would need to track the keywords on the results/search page from google. This is sooo sad.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Although it would be a little extra work on your part you could use this API to get your results without violating Google's TOS. Just do your search, record the top 40-50 URLs, make a custom search for those URLs, and then use the API and PHP to do your research. You get the same results and don't have to risk incurring Google's wrath.

Comment: Hello john, as far as i can understand from that api, you can only search INSIDE a LIST OF URLS/WEBPAGES, not the entire web. This is my problem :)

Comment: I got that part. That's why there are extra steps in accomplishing your goal but you can do it with that API.